# Recursive function always returns undefined JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've managed to create a script that has to count the LCF (**L**argest **C**ommon **F**actor ). My task was to create the script for exact this algorithm, so, I couldn't choose another one. But I always get `undefined` on return. What am I doing wrong?

I've checked the whole function with the `console.log` and it works right. It founds the right LCF, comes to `if` statement where it should return the variable value and this value even the number.
I've checked the value of this variable, I've checked the type of this var, everything should be ok, but it doesn't work.

```js
const checking = (num1, num2, t) => {
  if (num1 % t === 0) {
    if (num2 % t === 0) {
      return t;
    } else {
      checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
    }
  } else {
    checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
  }
}

const bruteforce = (num1, num2) => {
  //Checking if numbers are equal
  if (num1 === num2) return num1;
  //If no, defining minimal one
  let t = 0;
  num1 > num2 ? t = num2 : t = num1;

  let answer = checking(num1, num2, t);
}
```

I expect the output of var `t` value, but the actual output is always `undefined`

Comment: You need to return the result of calling the recursive function. **Every** path out of the function must return something. So `return checking(num1, num2, t - 1);`, not just `checking(num1, num2, t - 1);`, etc.

Comment: Try to minimize your code paths like so `return num1 % t === 0 && num2 % t === 0 ? t : checking(num1, num2, t - 1);`

Comment: You have only specified what checking should return if `num1 % t === 0` and `num2 % t === 0`. For all other cases it will return `undefined`.

Comment: @MisterJojo **l**argest **c**ommon **f**actor

Comment: @Игорь Александров, the larger the numbers get, the less performant this gets. a better approach would be to do the prime factorization of both numbers and the LCF is the product of all factors that appear on both sides.

Comment: @Thomas : thanks (this PGCD in French)

Comment: @MisterJojo, GGT in german, and even in english a more common term would be greatest common divisor (gcd) [and a few others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). But the code gives away what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Thomas I also imagined it was a "GCD", but as its algorithm is wrong I thought it could be something else. to use acronyms without explanation is not a good idea here, or everyone does not understand the globish (In inglish the correct accronym is GCD)

Answer (score 1):

When using a recursive function you should always return the call so the answer can travel up the stack:

```
const checking = (num1, num2, t) => {
  if (num1 % t === 0) {
    if (num2 % t === 0) {
      return t;
    } else {
      return checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
    }
  } else {
    return checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you recursive function recurses, it doesn't return anything.  It just calls itself:

```
checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
```

But does nothing with the *result* of that call.  Return that result:

```
return checking(num1, num2, t - 1);
```